# Unity3D Progress Bar with new GUI, slow updating?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created a simple progress bar that gets launched via a coroutine.  I yield out within a for...loop every quarter of a second (0.25f), yet the GUI's progress bar updates every ~1 second instead of every quarter of a second.  What am I doing wrong?  Or is this a bug?

```
IEnumerator Timer() {

    float time = 60f;
    float tick = 0;
    float progress = 0;
    float smoothTime = 4f;

    while (true) {

        progress = (tick/time) * 640f;
        Debug.Log("Tick: " + tick);

        for (int i = 0; i < smoothTime; i++) {
            // THIS SHOULD UPDATE EVERY 1/4th OF A SECOND BUT DOESN'T
            rawImageRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(progress/smoothTime, 10f); 
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f/smoothTime);
        }

        if (tick >= 60f) {
            Debug.Log("*** GAME OVER ***");
            break; 
        }
        tick++;
    }
}
```

The seconds count will appear in a GUI text label over and centered on the progress bar (that code isn't here because I'm having problems creating a smooth and accurate progress bar).

Using Unity3D 4.6.3 / C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, progress is only changed at the beginning of the while loop:

```
 progress = (tick/time) * 640f;
```

So, when you enter the for loop, and run the line:

```
rawImageRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(progress/smoothTime, 10f);
```

it runs 4 times for the same progress value, and that's why you only see changes once a second: the sizeDelta is changed 4 times per second to the same value.

Comment: Oh dear-me-my.  This is what happens when looking at your own code for weeks in and out -- the obvious becomes obscure.  Thanks.  I'd delete the question, but since you answered it, I'll give you the credit.

Comment: Thanks. A second pair of eyes tends to help ^^ Good luck.